# Removing the part of the url from the last slash (Google Sheets)

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a big list of urls. For example,

https://www.example.com/category1/product1/

https://www.example.com/en/category2/product-123/

https://www.example.com/de/category456/product-12-13/

I would need to get only the last part of each url without slashes:

product1

product-123

product-12-13

Will really appreciate it for helping with the formula.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the url's in column A, try

```
=Arrayformula(if(len(A2:A), REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A, ".*/(.*?)/$"),))
```

and see if that works?

[image: Example]